# PDO equivalent of mysql_num_rows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to be able to translate the mysql code below into PDO equivalent. Please can someone help me out as I have looked around and tried other examples but they are not working for me.

```
// Count Participants
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table2");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: If you're using fetch_assoc or something similar in PDO to get the result, you have an array and can just use `count`

Comment: @adeneo  Does this look alright?                                                         $result = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM table2");
$result->execute();
$num_rows = $result->count();

Answer (score 3):

You can either just issue a `count` query to the DB

```
$db    = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
$count = $db->query('SELECT count(*) FROM table2')->fetchColumn();
```

or get an array back that can be counted

```
$stmt  = $db->query('SELECT * FROM table2');
$rows  = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$count = count( $rows );
```

or get any kind of other resultset back, and count that etc.

Comment: For the first query, does that mean I can use the count to be inserted into a statement like this:                                                                 <?php

 echo "<br />There are " . $count . " participants.";                          ?>

Comment: A `count()` query returns a number of matches, so why not try it and see ?

Comment: @adeneo you will need to use `fetchAll`  otherwise you will always count 1 row with `fetch`

Comment: @adeneo: My code now works. This is what I used: $query = $db->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM table2");
 $query->execute();
 $num_rows= $query->fetchColumn();

Comment: Of course, fetchAll would only be required if you need to know the number of rows. To make things a little quicker, if you only need the equivalent of mysql_num_rows > 0, just use fetch().